# Short story about a voyage to harvest tissue from a dead angel

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to recall the name of a short story collection on audio.  The last story in the collection involved a sea voyage to a distant land - there was a giant dead angel and tissue growths from the inside were prized.

Comment: When did you listen to this?  Where did you get the collection?

Comment: For an audio-book specifically do you recall if it was a single narrator or an ensemble cast?

Comment: I am sure it was a single male narrator, source AudiobookBay.

Comment: Part of me wants to suggest "The General Zapped An Angel", but I don't remember a harvesting aspect.

Comment: Can you remember what the tissue samples were used for? A narcotic?

Comment: Not sure, but the crew got inside the skull to chip at the tissues, at the end they all turned on each other, I think the hero got done in by the femme fatale

Answer (score 6):

***[Towing Jehovah](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22294596-towing-jehovah)*** (1994) by James K. Morrow? It's the first book in the *[Godhead](https://www.goodreads.com/series/43601-godhead)* trilogy.

Where the Vatican charters a boat to tow the corpse of God to the pole, where they have constructed a tomb in a glacier?

From Goodreads:

> God is dead, and Anthony Van Horne must tow the corpse to the Arctic (to preserve Him from sharks and decomposition). En route Van Horne must also contend with ecological guilt, a militant girlfriend, sabotage both natural and spiritual, and greedy hucksters of oil, condoms, and doubtful ideas. Winner of a 1995 World Fantasy Award.